# Python - поиск максимума внутри диапазона

Tags: python

> Всем привет! Есть список а из которого рассчитывается накопительный
> итог (список х). Далее в списке х идет поиск минимального значения и
> максимального, которое должно быть строго (!) до минимума. Текущий
> вариант почему-то возвращает максимум всего списка х (41), а должен
> быть 17

```
import numpy as np

a=[17,-2,8,17,1,-7,3, -15,19, -13]
x=list(np.cumsum(a))
y=min(x)
z=max(x[:y])


print(f'list {x}')
print(f'minimum {y}')
print(f'maximum {z}')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что в срезе нужно использовать **индекс** минимального значения, а не само значение:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([17,-2,8,17,1,-7,3, -15,19, -13])
x = np.cumsum(a)
y = np.argmin(x) # <-- ищем индекс минимума!
z = np.min(x[:y])

print(f'list {x}')
print(f'minimum {x[y]}') # <-- значение минимума берём по индексу
print(f'maximum {z}')
```

Вывод:

```
list [17 15 23 40 41 34 37 22 41 28]
minimum 15
maximum 17
```